# How to do data validation formula for a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example, to apply list data validation to the 2nd column:

| Vehicle | Model |
| --- | --- |
| car |  |
| bike |  |
| car |  |

I would like to do a formula like this, but it errors:

```
=IF($A:$A=“car”, CarTable, BikeTable)
```

The error message is:

> “The Source currently evaluates to an error.”

And if I click continue, there is a dropdown button but it contains nothing.

If I put `A2:A4` instead of `A:A` it would work, but I need it applied to the actual column so that all cells in the column will have data validation (for when new new items are eventually entered).

How should I do this?

Comment: "but it errors:", what error does it show? Try creating a named range (myvehicles) for column A. Then change the formula to `=IF(myvehicles=“car”, CarTable, BikeTable)`.

Comment: The error message is “The Source currently evaluates to an error”. If I click continue, there is a dropdown button but it contains nothing. 
I tried your suggestion (highlighted the column (A:A) and set the name) and the same issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want column `A` to be formatted based on the value of cells in column `A`, you can use the following condition:

```
=A2="car"
```

And apply it to `A:A`

If you want multiple columns to be formated based on the values in column `A`, you will want to use absolute references:

```
=$A2="car"
```

And apply it to the desired range (ex.: `A:C`)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's definitely an issue: It seems like your reference range is incorrect. That's this bit: `$A:$A`. It's trying to evaluate the entire column and judge if it equals `"car"`.

Try using either `$A2` (presuming the first cell in your range is `B2`) or, depending on your version of Excel, `@$A:$A`. Both of these will return a single cell. The first case (`$A2`) will update the row referenced for each cell in the range with validation but the column will stay absolute thanks to `$`. The second one (`@$A:$A`) is basically the same in that it returns the cell in column `A` that's in the same row as the cell we're evaluating. In your case, these two work the same because the data in column `B` is on the same row as the data in column `A`.

---

It's also possible that the issue is that `CarTable` or `BikeTable` is more than a single column. If that's the case, adjust the named range to be a single column.

---

It's also possible that `CarTable` is an actual table. In that case, you can add the name of the column you want wrap the whole thing in `INDIRECT()` like this:

```
Indirect("CarTable[Model]")
```

Comment: I think I want to avoid putting the, for example, '2' in `$A2` because I want the data validation to extend beyond the table (i.e. be infinite) — putting the row number makes the data validation stop at the end of the table. 

`CarTable` is indeed a single column table. However `Indirect("CarTable[Model]")` evaluates to an error.

Comment: The `2` in the formula is relative and updates based on the range that has data validation. if you apply the data validation to the range `B2:B100000`, then cell `B2` will be based on `A2` and the cell `B456789` will be based on `A456789`. The `CarTable[Model]` was an example of how to fix it if `CarTable` is the name of an actual table and you need to call out the field *within* that table. I made up an example where the table has a field named `Model`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the '2' would be dynamic. The problem with applying e.g.  `B2:B100000` is that it leads to a large worksheet. 

My other data validated columns (which are also list-based but don't have `IF()`) have the data validation applied infinitely (i.e. to the actual column, not  to the column's first 100000 rows or the confines of the table) which is what I was hoping to be able to achieve here. Do you understand my issue?

Comment: @user4367814 Ah! You want to apply data validation to a small range of cells and have Excel expand that application downward as the data range grows. For that, I recommend using a [Table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) (on the Insert ribbon). Formatting applied to that will copy down. Here's [a little GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JViF9.gif) of me showcasing this.

Comment: @user4367814 I may have misunderstood. I think your best bet is to apply it to the entire column and use `=IF($A1="car"...` or `=IF(@$A:$A="car"...`. Applying it to the whole column is the same as applying it to `B1:B1048576` so using `$A1` with a relative row reference works out fine.

Comment: The limitation with tables is that if, for example, somebody inserts data 2 rows below the table (and perhaps deletes the blank the empty row) it'll break as all subsequent cells in the column will not have data validation. Many people will be entering data in the worksheet so it has to be resilient

Comment: Yes I think it looks like I'll have to do e.g. `B1:B1048576`, but it's not exactly the same as applying it directly to the column though because the document will have a tiny scrollbar and it won't be ideal to have such a mostly-empty long worksheet